# How to protect SQL express local offline Database without data encryption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, localdb, data-protection

I have one C# application that interacts with local SQL express database.
I need to protect this data from theft even from the user logged in.

Only application should be able to access the data and no other way should be able to fetch or see the data.

Please advise.

Comment: define _"protect from theft even from the user logged in"_. How are you expecting them to be able to steal the infomation (SQL attacks, direct access to the database files, breaking and entering, permission abuse etc). There are many methods that protect databases from unauthorised access.

Comment: Direct database use. I don't want user or any one other than the application to open the database by any means.Whether it is SQL server or some other utility that could show data from mdf file.I Don't want to encrypt data. I dont want to split data. I need something may be to lock the folder and only application could open it without much performance hit. Please tell me if there is any way.

Comment: Are you unable to host the database on a separate machine in the building or using a web based provider? one of the simplest solutions to this problem is to hide the database from the application using a service layer

Comment: If you install a MDF locally, then a local admin can do anything he wants with it. Unless you hard code and obfuscate an encryption algorithm. Regardless whats to stop a user sucking the data out manually from the front end?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but you can use a product that encrypts the SQL database files directly. Netlib Encryptionizer does this (disclosure: I am the CTO) and it can secure the MDF and LDF files so that even the DBA or Sysadmin can't read or reattach the files to another instance.
https://netlibsecurity.com/products/sql-express-encryption/